# what happens to a dict with no pointer

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a ponter to a `dict()` and I keep update it, like that:

```
def creating_new_dict():
   MyDict = dict()
   #... rest of code - get data to MyDict
   return MyDict

def main():
    while(1):
        MyDict = creating_new_dict()
        time.sleep(20)
```

I know that *MyDict* is a pointer to the `dict` so My question is what happens to the old data in *MyDict*?
Is it deleted or should I make sure it's gone?

Comment: http://www.digi.com/wiki/developer/index.php/Python_Garbage_Collection

Comment: We usually say "reference", eschewing the uncouth P word.  And the old `dict` is at that point available for garbage collection, so not -now-, but some time in the future, it will be collected.

Comment: Actually in CPython it's collected immediately since the object's reference count drops to zero. This might not be true for other implementations, though.

Comment: @kindall yes, I address that in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Coming back around to answer your question since nobody else did:

> I know that MyDict is a pointer to the dict

Ehhh.  `MyDict` is a *reference* to your `dict` object, not a pointer.  Slight digression follows:

---

You can't mutate immutable types within a function, because you're handling *references*, not pointers.  See:

```
def adder(x):
    x = x + 1

a = 0
adder(a)
a
Out[4]: 0
```

I won't go too far down the rabbit hole, but just this: there is nothing I could have put into the body of `adder` that would have caused `a` to change.  Because variables are references, not pointers.

---

Okay, we're back.

> so My question is what happens to the old data in MyDict?

Well, it's still there, in some object somewhere, but you blew up the reference to it.  The reference is no more, it has ceased to be.  In fact, there are exactly zero extant references to the old `dict`, which will be significant in the next paragraph!

> Is it deleted

It's not deleted *per se*, but you could basically *think* of it as deleted.  It has no remaining references, which means it is eligible for garbage collection.  Python's `gc`, when triggered, will come along and get rid of all the objects that have no remaining references, which includes all your orphaned `dict`s.

But like I said in my comment: `gc` will not be triggered -now-, but some time in the (possibly very near) future.  How soon that happens depends on.. stuff, including what flavor of python you're running.  cPython (the one you're probably running) will usually gc the object immediately, but **this is not guaranteed and should not be relied upon** - it is left up to the implementation.  What you can count on - the gc will come along and clean up *eventually.*  (well, as long as you haven't disabled it)

> or should I make sure it's gone?

Nooooo.  Nope.  Don't do the garbage collector's job.  Only when you have a very specific performance reason should you do so.

> I still don't believe you, show me an example.

Er, you said that, right?  Okay:

```
class DeleteMe:
    def __del__(self): #called when the object is destroyed, i.e. gc'd
        print(':(')

d = DeleteMe() 
d = DeleteMe() # first one will be garbage collected, leading to sad face
:(
```

And, like I said before, you shouldn't count on `:(` happening immediately, just that gc will happen eventually.